# 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I want to access root url of a Web application from a Windows forms Application.

```
string rooturl = Billing_XML_WebTracking.WebForm1.RootUrl;
string url = rooturl + "/WebForm1.aspx";
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

So I have added the below code to Web.config of the Web Application :

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</assemblies>
```

And the final code of Web.config file is

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But while building the solution, it is giving below error
The type 'System.Web.UI.Page' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: Add a reference to the assembly 'System.Web' to your winforms project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `References` you must add `System.Web.dll`